# Not sure my thread id in boost log is correct or not?

Tags: c++, boost

below is my full test codes, I print the current thread id, but it looks very long, is it correct? And because I am using BOOST_LOG_SCOPED_THREAD_TAG, can I log thread id in other threads?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/scoped_attribute.hpp>
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
void InitLog() {
  typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_ostream_backend > text_sink;
  boost::shared_ptr< text_sink > sink = boost::make_shared< text_sink >();
  sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
                     boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("sign.log"));
  sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
                     boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("csv.log"));

  sink->set_formatter (
               expr::format("[%1%]<%2%>(%3%): %4%")
               % expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
               % logging::trivial::severity
               % expr::attr<boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
               % expr::smessage
               );
  logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
  logging::add_common_attributes();
  BOOST_LOG_SCOPED_THREAD_TAG("ThreadID", boost::this_thread::get_id());
}
int main(int, char*[]) {
  InitLog();
  using namespace logging::trivial;
  src::severity_logger<severity_level> lg;
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, trace) << "A trace severity message";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, debug) << "A debug severity message";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, info) << "An informational severity message";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, warning) << "A warning severity message";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, error) << "An error severity message";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, fatal) << "A fatal severity message";
  return 0;
}
```

The test app generates two log files: sign.log and csv.log, they have same content like so:

```
[2013-12-23 23:38:47]<trace>(0x00007f1f8a173740): A trace severity message
[2013-12-23 23:38:47]<debug>(0x00007f1f8a173740): A debug severity message
[2013-12-23 23:38:47]<info>(0x00007f1f8a173740): An informational severity message
[2013-12-23 23:38:47]<warning>(0x00007f1f8a173740): A warning severity message
[2013-12-23 23:38:47]<error>(0x00007f1f8a173740): An error severity message
[2013-12-23 23:38:47]<fatal>(0x00007f1f8a173740): A fatal severity message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//! This function is executed in multiple threads
void thread_fun(boost::barrier& bar)
{

    // Here we go. First, identify the thread.
    BOOST_LOG_SCOPED_THREAD_TAG("ThreadID", boost::this_thread::get_id());

    // Now, do some logging
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LOG_RECORDS_TO_WRITE; ++i)
    {
        BOOST_LOG(test_lg::get()) << "Log record " << i;
    }
}
```

see : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/example/bounded_async_log/main.cpp